# Google calendar event create and Google business account

Tags: php, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-apps

I am using PHP and Google API for create the google calendar and invite the people. Previously it was worked. But now google change the API. So I also changed the library.

[Library](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client)

After that I got the permission issue. So I found the solution from google developer account.
**Delegate domain-wide authority to your service account**

https://developers.google.com/drive/web/delegation

But according to this method I didn't see any **Manage third party OAuth Client access**

Anybody know any solution or anyway to create the google calendar and invite people?

NOTE: I tried the gmail account. It is working. But when I try the google business account, I have above problem.

Screenshot

[image]

[image]

Comment: In the authentication->click on "Manage API client access". It is same as "Manage third party OAuth Client access" in the documentation.

Comment: @SGC You should make your comment an answer.

Answer (score 1):

In the authentication->click on "Manage API client access". It is same as "Manage third party OAuth Client access" in the documentation.